# Verifying if a cell based on 2 conditions in the column and row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, match, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I have the following spreadsheet. I want to be able to count the number of times a cell is not empty when the type in the same row is "C" of the same column (F279:F287). For example, I want to know how many cells are not empty in F279:F287 where in the same row as column A = "C".

The answer, in this case, will be 2.  I also want to check it on all columns F:N as 15 may not necessarily be in the same column.

I've been trying `Vlookup`, `Hlookup`, `countifs`, `counta(if)` and have not had any luck

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bdYw6ODAoIrS6i8hRuov2thYfK9RpKj_vRhdyJYigfs/edit#gid=159676829.  It's Under the sheet "Tournoi_1" and i want to compare the number 15 with cell A316

Answer (score 0):

> to know how many cells are not empty in F279:F287 where in the same row as column A = "C"

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(F279:F287; A279:A287="C")))
```

[image: 0]

---

> also want to check it on all columns F:N as 15 may not necessarily be in the same column

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(ROW(A$279); MATCH(L298; A$278:N$278; 0); 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(ROW(A$287); MATCH(L298; A$278:N$278; 0); 4)); A$279:A$287=M$297)))
```

[image: 0]